# ZonedDateTime parse to another format of ZonedDateTime

Tags: datetime, java-8, zoneddatetime

The `ZonedDateTime` currently in

```
`2020-06-07T14:10:00+01:00`
```

The format the `ZonedDateTime` that I am looking for

```
2020-06-07T13:10:24Z
```

Comment: Your current data is in `ZonedDateTime` or `String` ? ZonedDateTime don't represent any format, you can format it's data into String.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
ZonedDateTime.parse("2020-06-07T14:10:00+01:00").toInstant()
```

Or if you must have a `ZonedDateTime`:

```
ZonedDateTime.parse("2020-06-07T14:10:00+01:00").withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
String time = "2020-06-07T14:10:00+01:00";
```

Desired output format = `2020-06-07T13:10:24Z`

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(time,                      
        DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME);                   
System.out.println(zdt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT));
```

Prints

```
2020-06-07T13:10:00Z
```